# Promise returning as a function when wrapping callback function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to convert an existing callback based function from the crypto library to be used with es6 `async/await` in the method above it. Whenever I make a call to `generateSubkey(password,salt)` it returns `[function]`. Inside this if I call `toString()` it shows my methods code as opposed to executing it.

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
import Promise from 'bluebird';

async hashPassword(password) {

    try {
        // Create a salt with cryptographically secure method.
        let salt = await crypto.randomBytes(16);

        let subkey = await this.generateSubkey(password, salt);

        console.log(subkey);

    } catch (e) {

    }

}

generateSubkey(password, salt) {
    return new Promise.resolve((resolve, reject) => {
        return crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 10000, 32, 'sha256', (err, buffer) => {
            if (err) {
                reject();
            }
            resolve(buffer);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: You are returning `new Promise.resolve()` which resolves the Promise immediately. The resolve value will be your meant to be Promise-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whenever I make a call to generateSubkey(password,salt) it returns [function].

To use the promise constructor with the executor callback, it's `return new Promise(…)`, not `return new Promise.resolve(…)`.

> I'm trying to convert an existing callback based function from the crypto library to be used with ES8 `async/await`

You might be looking for [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original). No need to bring in Bluebird<sup>1</sup> and use the `new Promise` constructor.

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
import util from 'util';

const pbkdf2Async = util.promisify(crypto.pbkdf2);
function generateSubkey(password, salt) {
    return pbkdf2Async(password, salt, 10000, 32, 'sha256');
}
```

<sub>1: If you still want to use Bluebird, it does bring [a `promisify` function](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) as well :-)</sub>

Comment: Now this looks much more appealing, going to give that a go and hopefully scrap the entire function.

Answer (score 2):

You are resolving the newly created promise by calling `Promise.resolve` immediately. Create the promise this way:

`return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... });`

Btw you could also use bluebird's `Promise.promisify` (not tested):

```
const promisePbkdf2 = Promise.promisify(crypto.pbkdf2);

let subkey = await promisePbkdf2(password, salt, 10000, 32, 'sha256');
```

In newer node, there is also promisify support available (without bluebird):

http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html